# Query a GDALDriverH or GDALDriver without a dataset to find out if it is raster or vector?

Tags: gdal, vector, drivers

Is there any way to query a `GDALDriverH` (in C) or `GDALDriver` (in C++) to determine if it works for vector formats or raster formats (or with both, such as fGDB)?

In my iOS app utilising GDAL 2.2, I am building a list of all available drivers, and a I want to inform the users which Vector drivers are available without displaying raster drivers.

At present, I can only figure out how to display all drivers (both raster and vector).

Comment: That's a good question.. historical releases GDALDriver were raster specific and OGRDriver were vector but now that all drivers have been combined and the use of OGR is depreciated how would you know?... there might be something in GDALGetDriverCreationOptionList https://gdal.org/doxygen/gdal_8h.html#a6fb28681f92299e4e6def85832a78288 which might answer other questions like what pixel types and band counts are valid for the driver.

Comment: I did have a look at the XML generated for GDALGetDriverCreationOptionList for some of the drivers, and I couldn't see anything that would be reliable for this purpose, unfortunately.

Comment: `GetMetadataItem(GDAL_DCAP_VECTOR)`

Comment: Hey that works!  Thanks so much (I can also see there's a whole world of other GDAL meta-data out there that I was unaware of!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved - thanks to @user2856 comment (above).

Use the `GDALGetMetadataItem()` function (C), or the  `GetMetadataItem()` method (C++).  Passing in a `pszName` argument of `GDAL_DCAP_VECTOR` returns `"YES`" for a vector driver and `NULL` otherwise (as far as I can tell - I haven't actually found the exact behaviour documented, as yet).

For my iOS Swift code I can just call the C function directly in this case:

```swift
GDALGetMetadataItem(driver, GDAL_DCAP_VECTOR, nil) == nil {
    //  IS NOT VECTOR
} else {
    //  IS VECTOR
}
```

Comment: I dunno if it will cause you any issues, but note that some drivers handle both vector and raster data. e.g GeoPackage.

Comment: Yep.  No worries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the only solution that I've found so far.  It's not ideal, but it works...

- Hard code a list of Vector Driver Names, based on the driver short names found at:  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html
- Check if each driver's short name is in the hard-coded list of Vector Driver Names

This is a little kludgy, and obviously not going to dynamically pick up new drivers when the GDAL project adds them (if I upgrade to a later version of GDAL).  But it works for now.

I'd still be keen to hear if anybody has a better and dynamic way of determining if a driver supports vector formats.